# Need help showing the exact sequence of finite abelian groups splits.

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Say $0 \to G_1 \xrightarrow f G_2 \xrightarrow g G_3 \to 0$ is exact and gcd$(|G_1|=n, |G_3|=m)=1.$ Then the sequence splits.

We have that there exist $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $mr+ns=1$. We then define a map $\beta:G_3 \to G_2$ such that $\beta(g_3)=mrg_2$ where $g_3=g(g_2)$.

I don't know how to show that this map is well defined.

Comment: How does $mrg_2$  change if you pick another preimage of $g_3$? That is: if $g_2'$ is another element of $G_2$ such that $g(g_2')=g_3$, what relation is there between $mrg_2$ and $mrg_2$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That would mean $g_2'=g_2$, I think, but honestly I'm not really getting what we're doing actually.

Comment: No it would not mean that (the map $g$ is not injective, in general, so it *cannot* mean that)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez If you could ELI5 how to show it is well defined, that would mean alot.

Comment: That is precisely what Tsemo did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to say that $gcd(|G_1|=n,|G_3|=m)=1$. $G_1$ is a subgroup of $G_2$ thus by Lagrange, the cardinal of $G_1$ divides the cardinal of $G_2$.

You have $an+bm=1$, let $h:G_3\rightarrow G_2$ be a section. i.e $g(h(x))=x$, write $l(x)=h(x)^{an}$, we have $l(xy)l(y)^{-1}l(x)^{-1}=h(xy)^{an}h(y)^{-an}h(x)^{-an}=(h(xy)h(y)^{-1}h(x)^{-1})^{an}=1$ since the order of $G_1$ is $n$ and $h(xy)h(y)^{-1}h(x)^{-1}\in G_1$.

We also have $g(l(x))=g(h(x)^{an})=x^{an}=x^{1-bm}=x$ since the order of $G_3$ is $m$. We deduce that $l$ is a morphism of groups, thus the sequence splits.

Comment: $G_1\leq G_2$ since the groups are commutative.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is it possible if you could also comment on the approach I'm trying?

Comment: @Smokesalot, your approach is **exactly** the same as Tsemo's...

Comment: (Tsemo, your «We deduce that $l$ is a morphism of groups» should be at the end of the 2nd paragraph *or* it should be «...a morphism of groups which is  section of $g$» or something like that :-) )

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm still not sure how we can just assume $g(h(x))=x$.

Comment: Because $g$ is surjective

Comment: Yes, but how come it's the identity map?

Comment: what is the identity map?

Comment: the map $g \dot h$.

Comment: Sorry if I'm bothering you. If we're assuming $h$ is a right inverse of the surjective map $g$, then I understand your reasoning but why is $h(xy)h(y)^{-1}h(x)^{-1}\in G_1$? Sorry, but can you please explain some more.

Comment: because $g(h(xy)h(y)^{-1}h(x)^{-1})=g(h(xy))g(h(y))^{-1}g(h(x)^{-1})=xyy^{-1}x^{-1}=1$, so $h(xy)h(y)^{-1}h(x)^{-1}$ is in the kernel of $g$ which is $G_1$.